# nested ristriction in hibernate on single class

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I am trying to add criteria on dependent field of class which is not in table.
person class has age and weight fields.. 
Now I want list of persons whose age is exactly less than his weight by 5.

In SQL Query will be something like this:

`select * 
from Person p
Where p.age = p.weight +5 ;`

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum there's sqlRestriction

```
Restrictions.sqlRestriction("AGE = WEIGHT + 5")
```

I don't see any way (short of implementing your own Criterion object) to do this with the criteria api.  You might be better just using hql.